Incorrectly registered Broadcast receiver (Google Play uploading and publishing issue)
I'm stuck on some issue about uploading my android application to Google play store.
enter image description here
I fixed some code in the project which is still android 13. However right after I upload the .aap file, it shows the above issue.
Is their any problem on my code using registerReceiver method? or any environmental problem of my local settings? The SDK version is 34, jdk is 1.8.0-adoptopenjdk
I would really appreciate if someone give me some advises.
I tried this code, and also modify my AndroidManifest.xml file, so it contains exported="true".
boolean listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps = false;
int receiverFlags;
if (listenToBroadcastsFromOhterApps) {
    receiverFlags = ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED;
} else {
    receiverFlags = ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED;
}

ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, myReceiver, intentFilter, receiverFlags);

